# Mac Pro (5,1 - Mid 2010) + Mini DisplayPort to DVI Adapter + DVI Monitor = blank LCD

Tags: display, graphics, mac-pro

I just received a new 2.8 Ghz Mac Pro with an ATI 5770. I have one LCD connected to the DVI port which is working fine. I have another DVI LCD connected over a mini DisplayPort to DVI adapter to one of the mini DisplayPort ports. This mini DisplayPort to DVI LCD doesn't register at all.

I've tried three different models of LCDs. System Profiler simply says "No Display Connected." I have tried restarting numerous times and the only other possible solution I've read is to reset the PRAM. I'd like to know if that's actually worth my time or if I'm missing some other configuration change that's necessary.

Comment: When you put the Mini DisplayPort adapter in the the Display port does the screen flicker?

Comment: @MHrappstead - No, the display never acts as if it is connected at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mini DP adapter was not fully plugged into the machine.  It required a little more force than I was comfortable using to fully seat.